# How to linearize the product of an integer and a binary variable?

Tags: linear-programming, pulp

I am implementing an algorithm in ["An optimization-based approach to network inference"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03542),
and have some trouble in linearizing the product of an integer and a binary variable. The author in that paper prompts as follows,

> Suppose that a bilinear term has the form ib, where b is a binary variable and i is an integer variable lower bounded by 0 and upper bounded by I. The product term ib can be linearized as follows. Replace the term ib with a new integer variable z and add four constraints: z <= Ib, z <= i, z >= i-(1-b)I, and z >= i.

I use pulp to solve this problem, should I just abandon the last constraint, z>=i?

I am a new leaner in linear programming.

Comment: Maybe they just meant z >= 0;

Comment: Yeah, you are right. 英雄所见略同

Comment: FYI, questions like this belong on or.stackexchange.com